# Regex Replacement with Repetition, How do I replace each "\r\n" in X number of occurrences of ".+?\r\n"?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a very long list with each item separated by a line break. I want to group everything into groups of up to 1000 if possible, less if not, separated by commas.

So when using something like... `(.+?(\r\n)){1000}` how would I replace the `\r\n` match of each repetition with a comma?

Also, how would I make it match up to 1000 if possible, if not, as many as possible (for the group of the list)? I thought it would be {,1000} but that errors.

Comment: using `{1,1000}` should work for the repetitions (or `{0,1000}`)... but do you want to replace every `\r\n` or just the 1000th occurrence?

Comment: Every \r\n. For example. The number I am actually working with are 17576 lines. I want to convert it to 18 lines of 1000 items each (besides the last one) separated by commas. I know a few other ways i could do this pretty quickly but I am really curious if there is a way to replace per-repetition.

I actually tried {0,1000} but it matched everything as a zero length match

Comment: Not sure I follow, then. How will they be grouped in groups of 1000 if you replace everything by a comma?

Comment: Would you be fine with this split into two separate replace operations. E.g. replace every newline `\R+` with `,` and then replace every 1000th comma `^((?:[^,]*,){1000})`with `\1\n`

Comment: @JonM That is how I did it, I was just hoping to find out if there is a way to do it in one operation because similar things have come up before and I feel like there should be a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with a single replace but it is possible with two replace operations.

First replace `\R+` with `,`

Then replace `^((?:[^,]*,){1000})` with `\1\r\n`

and if you are worried about the original lines containing commas that will get misinterpreted you can use a placeholder string e.g.

First replace `\R+` with `!!--PLACEHOLDER--!!`

Then replace `^((?:(?:(?!!!--PLACEHOLDER--!!).)*!!--PLACEHOLDER--!!){1000})` with `\1\r\n`

The replace all placeholders `!!--PLACEHOLDER--!!` with whichever delimiter you'd like `,`